# How do I put cloudformation intrinsic functions inside a string in json

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

"Integration": { "IntegrationHttpMethod" : "GET",  "Type" : "HTTP", "Uri" : "http://{"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyEC2Instance", "PublicIp" ] }:8080/rest"

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [Sub](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) function. If you wanted to put the result of `{"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyEC2Instance", "PublicIp" ] }` in a your example string, it could be done with

```
"MyGatewayMethod": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
  "Properties": {

    ...

    "Integration": {
      "Type": "HTTP",
      "IntegrationHttpMethod": "GET",
      "Uri": { "Fn::Sub":"http://${MyEC2Instance.PublicIp}:8080/rest" }
    }
  }
}
```

The `Sub` method can be used to substitute both `GetAtt` values and `Ref` values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I solved it using this function Fn::Join

"Integration": { "IntegrationResponses": [{"StatusCode": 200}], "IntegrationHttpMethod" : "GET",  "Type" : "HTTP", "Uri" : {"Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "http://", {"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyEC2Instance", "PublicIp" ] }, ":8080/rest" ] ] } }

}
          }